# WatermarkExtender blinking when when UpdatePanel triggers on Timer

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, watermark

I put `UpdatePanel` with a `Timer` as a trigger in my webpage.  Also, outside of the panel, I put a `TextBox` with a [`WatermarkExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx).

When the timer ticks, the `UpdatePanel` refreshes. Also, the watermark blinks (it disappears from the text box and reappears). And this happens every 1 second.  This is a big issue.

Any help please?

Comment: May be this will help you!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367813/ajaxcontroltoolkit-watermark-extender-timer-blink

Comment: Does the timer trigger a postback? It seems likely that the blinking watermark is the result of the control being unloaded and reloaded. Mostly likely because of some postback type of event

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fix this because of how the extender works. It actually swaps out textboxes on postback.  The only way to fix would be to manually write your own extender js code.  You can read more about this problem here

http://forums.asp.net/p/1073683/1605937.aspx

and here

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/rewriting_the_textboxwatermark.html