# Ajaxcontroltoolkit watermark extender timer blink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've an ASP.NET page on which I've

1. 1 Timer (Tick event is trigger for update panel)
2. 1 Update Panel
3. 1 Label (in Update Panel)
4. 1 TextBox
5. 1 WaterMark extender (for TextBox)

The textbox and watermarkextander are out of the updatepanel, there are some other object in page but I am not listing them, the timer don't affect them. When I write something in textbox there is no problem but when the textbox is empty and the watermarkextender is active on timer tick the watermark text is blinking.

What could be the problem ?.

The updatepanel works fine, no other object is affected on timer tick, but somehow the watermark text is blinking.

Could you please help me about this issue ?

asp.net page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        WebForm_OnSubmit = Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWatermarkBehavior._originalWebForm_OnSubmit;
    });
</script>


    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBox1_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
            runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
            WatermarkText="Some Text">
        </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design feature of WatermarkExtender control. The reason of such behavior is to prevent submitting watermark text to server as value of target textbox.

You can avoid such behavior with adding script below **AFTER** ScriptManager control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.Application.add_load(function () 
     {
          WebForm_OnSubmit = Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWatermarkBehavior._originalWebForm_OnSubmit;
     });
</script>
```

Be warned though, that in this case you need explicitly ignore watermarked textboxes values on server if it equals to the watermark text.

Comment: what do you mean ? is it by default blinking when some Timer is ticking on page ?

Comment: Yes, it blinking by default on each postback. I've update my answer with possible solution to avoid blinking.

Comment: I've added the code to my page but it's still blinking, please note that there is no postback on timer, I've a label and I am getting some value from database on every timer tick I am not sure that creates some postback effect.

Comment: You can avoid such behavior with adding script below **AFTER** ScriptManager control